# Seek to a position before playing video

Tags: c++, qt, libvlc

I want to seek to a position before playing a video :

```
player= new VlcMediaPlayer(instance);
player->setPosition(pos);
player->setTime(time);
player->play();
```

but it does not work and instead I used this code:

```
player= new VlcMediaPlayer(instance);
player->play();
player->setPosition(pos);
player->setTime(time);
```

it now works but first plays the video (and shows some frames of the begining of the file) , is there any way to seek to a position before playing?

Comment: Try calling `pause()` before setting the position/time and then `play()` afterwards and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `VlcMediaPlayer` is but seeking in `libvlc` is done with  [libvlc_media_player_set_time](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga2f3347645100660ffae553387171e398) call. And as you can see in the documentation it requires to be called on the video *being played*. So you have to call `play` before you can call `seek`. But you can `pause` right after the `play` and then `seek`. That should do the job.

The [link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=106713) to the libvlc forum containing the similar question.

Comment: none of the above solutions work, and it yet plays the first frame of the file!

Comment: @abdolahS, well, you don't have much choice here. The only thing I can propose you is to register your own callbacks for the vlc and ignore frames while some flag is not set and draw frames when the flag is set. It will allow you to start playing without producing any images.